# What USB to UART chip provides highest data rates with Arduino boards?

Tags: usb, hardware, uart

Checking out online stores for a USB/TTL adapter, I came across a wide range of products, and I'm having a hard time selecting the one which would achieve the highest data rate. I was comparing datasheets of the chips I have seen so far, to understand which baud rates are supported:

- [FT232R](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf) (FTDI): 183 to 3M baud, including **250k**, **500k** and **1M**, 128 RX / 256 TX FIFO
- [PL2303](http://www.electronicaestudio.com/docs/PL2303.pdf) (Prolific): 75 to 1.2M baud, not including 250k, 500k and 1M, 256 RX / 256 TX FIFO
- [CP2102](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/CP2102-9.pdf) (Silicon Labs): 300 to 921600 baud, including **250k** and **500k**, 576 RX / 640 TX FIFO
- [CH340G](http://cdn2.boxtec.ch/pub/diverse/ch340g-datasheet.pdf) (WCH): 50 to **2M** baud, not including 250k, 500k and 1M, unknown FIFO size

As explained [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/299/13327), 500k, 1M and 2M are particularly important, because those are the highest baud rates supported with 16MHz crystals. Moreover, data transmission becomes CPU-limited above 500k, so real data rates are practically the same with all three baud rates.

Am I right to assume that in order to get the highest data rate, I essentially have to stay away from PL2303, and prefer FT232R adapters, the other two chips being in the middle? Or are there other factors that I didn't take into account which may affect my choice?

Comment: If you really want a high data rate then you should use an Arduino that supports USB natively so you can bypass the bridge entirely.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, the 32u4 for example does support USB

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Obviously, the question makes no sense for boards with native USB support. If I were to use Atmega32u4, why would I be shopping for a UART adapter?

Comment: At higher data rates the quality of the connection between the UART bridge and the main MCU becomes a factor. I have had reliable communication between FT232 and a PIC32 at 3Mbaud with both chips on the same board and properly routed traces. With separate boards I struggle to get reliable communication at 2Mbaud with 1Mbaud being about the limit.

Comment: For high throughput UART isn't really the best technology. As mentioned before you really want to go for direct USB if at all possible. It's all about selecting the right chip to build your project around, not just plumping for the "default" option.

Comment: @Majenko *With separate boards I struggle to get reliable communication at 2Mbaud* - this is a very important point IMO, it means that CP2102 may be actually faster than CH340G in this case. Regarding your second comment, I agree that UART isn't the best for high throughput, but when you have a choice between increasing the baud rate and migrating the project to a board with native USB support, a good UART chip may save you a lot of time.

Comment: I guess that another parameter to consider is the amount of internal buffers in these devices. To reach higher throughput you end up having to optimize the Arduino HardwareSerial code (for higher baudrate) and find faster methods to do conversion (e.g. dtoa). These are some of the tricks I did in Cosa to reach >90% effective throughput for up to 2 Mbit. Please see forum for further details https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=150299.555

Comment: @MikaelPatel I have added FIFO sizes to my question. Do they have a big impact on the throughput in practice?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Thanks for adding the FIFO size. It is actually important to understand how data flows. The USB signalling/protocol is not each character and it has its own "baudrate". Buffering allows bursts of packages and reduction of the signaling overhead (upstream), and helps even out bit-rate (downstream).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my experience with the above chips over the last two years:

**FT232R** is the fastest, works well with any baudrates. UART adapters with it are sometimes more expensive than alternatives.

**PL2303** is good if you don't plan to go faster than 115200. Additionally, it has the strongest 3.3V reference (available on some adapters as 3.3V output) which can be abused as a 3.3V 20mA power supply. Other chips will refuse to work if you draw more than 5mA from the 3.3V reference.

Prolific is currently fighting against clones by making their up-to-date drivers incompatible with non-original chips, so if your adapter won't work in Windows with code 10, take a look at [this page](http://www.totalcardiagnostics.com/support/Knowledgebase/Article/View/92/20/prolific-usb-to-serial-fix-official-solution-to-code-10-error).

**CP2102** which looks great in theory didn't work well for me (in Windows 10, with driver v10.1.3). Bulk data transfers at 115200 were in some cases 4 times as slow compared to other chips.

**CH340G** has a sketchy-looking windows driver, but otherwise works quite well and is often the cheapest option available. Unfortunately, it lack the intermediate baud rates, and getting 2Mbps UART link to work may be hard sometimes. Arduino clones which have this chip on-board do work at 2Mbps without issues (the ones I have seen do, anyway).