# CH340 max serial speed

Tags: serial, usb, clones

With an Arduino-like board using a CH340 USB Serial chip, I'd like to send text lines as fast as possible to a Raspberry Pi through USB using the *Serial.println()* function. The problem is that when I set the serial speed to values above 230 400 with the *Serial.begin(speed)* function, the Arduino console crashes and the C program on the Rapsberry Pi displays garbage in its console, even though I set the same serial speed.

Short examples :

```
Serial.begin(230400);
Serial.println("Test !"); // Works fine.

Serial.begin(250000);     // Or any speed above 250 000.
Serial.println("Test !"); // Doesn't work at all.
```

[This answered question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/296/how-high-of-a-baud-rate-can-i-go-without-errors) states that 2 Mbauds is possible, so I'm a bit lost.

The Arduino IDE console offers various speed from 300 to 2 000 000 bauds, so why don't speeds above 230 400 work ?

Comment: What type of Uno? Clone? Check what USB bridge is used on your board.

Comment: Cheap Chinese clone. The chip seems to be a CH340G.

Comment: CH340G does not support 250 Kbps. See page 5, https://www.insidegadgets.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ch340g-datasheet.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the datasheet and this information. But according to the document, speeds like 460 800 bauds and 2 000 000 bauds should work, so why would this not be the case with my board ?

Comment: Add the line "while (!Serial); " after "Serial.begin()" or simply a delay. The USB handshake might take some time and the first character lost.

Comment: Please remember that the baudrate is not the USB transfer rate. It is between the MCU and the USB bridge. Also the max sustained baudrate is approx. 100-200 Kbps with the Arduino HardwareSerial implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your help and reminder. My _print()_ are in a _while_ loop, and it's not a problem if I miss a few characters at the beginning. What is the HarwareSerial implementation ? I see it's a custom version of _Serial_, but what is it for ?

Comment: The HardwareSerial class is an implementation of the Arduino Serial class that uses the MCU/AVR UART (hardware serial). The class (internals) are interrupt driven and uses ring-buffers to store incoming and outgoing characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CHG340 supports common baud rates: 50, 75, 100, 110, 134.5, 150, 300, 600, 900, 1200, 1800, 2400, 3600, 4800, 9600, 14400, 19200, 28800, 33600, 38400, 56000, 57600, 76800, 115200, 128000, 153600, 230400, 460800, 921600, 1500000, 2000000 baud.

**250 000 baud** isn't supported by that IC.

The Baud steps is either 200% or 150% of the previous value (There is exceptions).

**Tested and working Baud rates.**

I used putty as serial monitor since the built in monitor didn't have all baud rates preprogrammed.

**SpeedTest.ino**

```
// Serial port Baudrates:
// const int Speed = 115200;
// const int Speed = 128000;
// const int Speed = 153600;
// const int Speed = 230400;
// const int Speed = 460800;
// const int Speed = 921600;
// const int Speed = 1500000;
const int Speed = 2000000;

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial:
  Serial.begin(Speed);

  // Initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("Speed :  ");
  Serial.println(Speed);
}
```

Comment: This helped me, thanks ! Actually, I've found that my problem is due to serial latency, but I still managed to communicate at 1 Mbaud.

Comment: I have tested 3000000, which worked for me. See also https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/ch340-usb-uart-speed-tests/

Comment: the windows driver only goes to 128000

Comment: I have seen commenst that speeds abowe 115200 is "unstable" in both windows and linux

Answer (score -1):

There may just be a workaround to allow this adapter to operate at 250000 baud (at least in the Raspberry Pi). The author of this article:  http://dmxpi.blogspot.com/2014/04/dmx-on-raspberry-pi-start-here.html has modified the linux driver and claims it works. I hope this helps.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the method/steps employed in the link. If the link dies then your answer will not be as useful as it could be.

Comment: i agree with @Greenonline